# Проблема прокрутки в UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

Имеется XIB `UIViewController` с вставленным в него `UICollectionView`, так-же `UICollectionView` использует `AutoLayout` и растягивается по краям `UIViewController`.
Я создаю ячейки и секции путем встаки.
А так же опускаюсь вниз до последней ячейки.

```
private func addNewMessage() {
let tuplForAdd = dataSource.newMessage()
if tuplForAdd.needNewSection {
  collectionView!.insertSections(dataSource.indexSet)
} else {
  collectionView!.insertItems(at: [tuplForAdd.indexPath])
}
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: tuplForAdd.indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Все работает прекрасно пока не прописываю сверху небольшой `contentInset`

```
collectionView.contentInset.top = 64
```

После этого прокрутка начинается не сразу, а после того как скрол опуститься по высоте ниже основного окна на 64. Как можно это решить ?

P/S Решением не может быть layout.sectionInset(так-как от него зависит высота хедер секции)

Comment: Посмотрите на этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993409/uicollectionview-with-contentinset-is-not-scrolling-all-the-way-down, возможно решение вам подойдет

Comment: Простите что не описал вопрос более качественно, я уже смотрел эту ссылку, проблема заключается в том что у меня нет storyboard, я пытался в коде менять переменную   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;  Но это не дало никаких результатов.